# Define the binary exponential operator CARAT in Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I am trying to define binary exponential operator in lambda calculus say operator CARAT. For example, this operator may take two arguments, the lambda encoding of number 2 and the lambda encoding of number 4, and computes the lambda encoding of number 16. I don't my answer is right or wrong but It took a day for me to do so. I have used church numerals definition.

Here is my answer. Please correct me if my answer is wrong. I don't how to do it exactly in a right way. If someone knows then please help me to figure out short answer.

A successor function, `next`, which adds one, can define the natural numbers in terms of `zero` and `next`:

```
1 = (next 0)    
2 = (next 1)
  = (next (next 0))    
3 = (next 2)
  = (next (next (next 0)))
```

From the above conclusion, we can define the function `next` as follows:

```
next = λ n. λ f. λ x.(f ((n f) x))
one  = (next zero)
     => (λ n. λ f. λ x.(f ((n f) x)) zero)
     => λ f. λ x.(f ((zero f) x))
     => λ f. λ x.(f ((λ g. λ y.y f) x)) -----> (* alpha conversion avoids clash *)
     => λ f. λ x.(f (λ y.y x))
     => λ f. λ x.(f x)
```

Thus, we can safely prove that….

```
zero = λ f. λ x.x
one = λ f. λ x.(f x)
two = λ f. λ x.(f (f x))
three = λ f. λ x.(f (f (f x)))
four = λ f. λ x.(f (f (f (f x))))
:
:
:
Sixteen = λ f. λ x.(f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f x))))))))))))))))
```

Addition is just an iteration of successor. We are now in a position to define addition in terms of `next`:

```
m next n => λx.(nextm x) n => nextm n => m+n
add = λ m. λ n. λ f. λ x.((((m next) n) f) x)
four = ((add two) two)
     => ((λ m. λ n. λ f. λ x.((((m next) n) f) x) two) two)
     => (λ n. λ f. λ x.((((two next) n) f) x)two)
     => λ f. λ x.((((two next) two) f x)
     => λ f. λ x.(((( λ g. λ y.(g (g y)) next) two) f x)
     => λ f. λ x.((( λ y.(next (next y)) two) f) x)
     => λ f. λ x.(((next (next two)) f) x)
     => λ f. λ x.(((next (λ n. λ f. λ x.(f ((n f) x)) two)) f) x)
```

After substituting values for ‘next’ and subsequently ‘two’, we can further reduce the above form to

```
     => λ f. λ x.(f (f (f (f x))))
```

i.e. four.

Similarly, Multiplication is an iteration of addition. Thus, Multiplication is defined as follows:

```
mul = λ m. λ n. λ x.(m (add n) x)
six = ((mul two) three)
 => ((λ m. λ n. λ x.(m (add n) x) two) three)
 => (λ n. λ x.(two (add n) x) three)
 => λ x.(two (add three) x
 => ( λf. λx.(f(fx)) add three) 
 =>( λx.(add(add x)) three)
 => (add(add 3))
 => ( λ m. λ n. λ f. λ x.((((m next) n) f) x)add three)
 => ( λ n. λ f. λ x.((( three next)n)f)x)add)
 => ( λ f. λ x.((three next)add)f)x)
```

After substituting values for ‘three’, ‘next’ and subsequently ‘add’ and then again     for ‘next’, the above form will reduce to

```
 => λ f. λ x.(f (f (f (f (f (f x))))))
```

i.e. six.

Finally, exponentiation can be defined by iterated multiplication

Assume exponentiation function to be called CARAT

```
CARAT = λm.λn.(m (mul n) )
sixteen => ((CARAT four) two)
 => (λ m. λ n.(m (mul n) four) two)
 => (λ n.(two (mul n)four
 => (two (mul four))
 => ((λ f. λ x.(f (f x))))mul)four)
 => (λ x. (mul(mul x))four)
 => (mul(mul four))))
 => (((((λ m. λ n. λ x.(m (add n) x)mul)four)
 => ((((λ n. λ x.(mul(add n) x)four)
 => (λ x.(mul(add four) x))
 => (λ x (λ m. λ n. λ x.(m (add n) x add)four) x
 => (λ x (λ n. λ x. (add(add n) x)four)x
 => (λ x (λ x (add (add four) x) x)
 => (λ x (λ x (λ m. λ n. λ f. λ x((((m next) n) f) x)add )four) x) x)
 => (λ x (λ x (λ n. λ f. λ x(((add next)n)f)x)four)x)x)
 => (λ x (λ x (λ f. λ x((add next)four)f)x)x)x) 
 => (λ x (λ x (λ f. λ x((λ m. λ n. λ f. λ x((((m next) n) f) x)next)four)f)x)x)x)
 => (λ x (λ x (λ f. λ x((λ n. λ f. λ x.(((next next)n)f)x)four)f)x)x)x)
 => (λ x (λ x (λ f. λ x((λ f. λ x ((next next)four)f)x)f)x)x)x)
 => (λ x (λ x (λ f. λ x((λ f. λ x(((λ n. λ f. λ x.(f ((n f) x))next)four)f)x)f)x)x)x)
```

Now, reducing the above expression and substituting for ‘next’ and ‘four’ and  further reducing, we get the following form

```
λ f. λ x.(f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f (f x))))))))))))))))
```

i.e. sixteen.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, re-write `next = λ n. λ f. λ x.(f ((n f) x))` as

```
next = λ num. λ succ. λ zero. succ (num succ zero)
```

In lambda-calculus parentheses are used just for grouping; an application is signified by juxtaposition of terms, i.e. just by writing one term next to another, and associates to the left.

How are we to read the above? It's a lambda term. When it is applied to some other lambda term, say `NUM`, it will reduce to a lambda term `λ succ. λ zero. succ (NUM succ zero)`. This will be the immediate result, a representation of the next number of a given number represented by `NUM`. We can read *it* as saying to us, *"I don't know how to calculate the successor, or what it means to be a zero, but if both are supplied to me I will produce some result according to them, and according to the lambda-term `NUM` that was used to create me, by supplying those means of calculation to `NUM` and then applying its result again to the successor function as given to me"*.

This of course was assuming that `NUM` respects same assumptions and operates in consistent ways. In particular, `ZERO`, when applied to an `s` and a `z`, must return `z`:

```lisp
ZERO = λ s. λ z. z  ; == λ a. λ b. b == ...
```

Everything else follows from this.